# How can I pass the success (or failure) of a command to a variable?

Tags: shell-script, exit-status

I am running `rsnapshot` to do backups of my NAS. I am forwarding the output of the command (e.g. `rsnapshot hourly`, `rsnapshot daily` etc.) to /tmp/rsnapshot_stats_hourly. In another script, I'd like to define a variable based on the outcome of the command / what's in the stats file. So I want to define the variable `"$status"` to be either `"success"` or `"failure"` based on whether there were or weren't errors while executing rsnapshot.

Can somebody help me with that one? My skills are very low in this regard unfortunately. Thanks.

Comment: The rsnapshot man page [has exit values](http://www.rsnapshot.org/rsnapshot.html#exit_values)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comment to the question **man rsnapshot** says:

> EXIT VALUES
>
> ```
>        0  All operations completed successfully
>
>        1  A fatal error occurred
>
>        2  Some warnings occurred, but the backup still finished
> ```

So you can modify your command line for example:

```
rsnapshot ... with_all_arguments ; [ $? == 0 ] && rm -f flag.file || touch flag.file
```

Or the same:

```
if rsnapshot ... with_all_arguments ; then
    rm -f flag.file 
else 
    touch flag.file
fi
```

And from other script just check the *flag.file* existance.

But **much better** to use rsnapshot's log-option and than check log-file.

Comment: After both of you pointed out the exit values - which I didn't knew about before - I edited my initial post to what my script looks like right now. It works fairly well on my Synology NAS. 
Thanks!